# Custom Reset Password with broker() ignored in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use a different type of user for the password reset. I use `broker()` as mentioned several times on the internet but it is completely ignored !

In my CustomForgotController

```
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
     /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('digitalpet_users');
    }

public function sendResetLink(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT ? response()->json(200) : response()->json($status, 500);
    }
```

I also added this in auth.php (providers and guards are already configured and works)

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table'    => 'password_resets',
            'expire'   => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'digitalpet_users' => [
            'provider' => 'digitalpet_users',
            'table'    => 'password_resets',
            'expire'   => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Can you tell me why my application completely ignores this setting (the default users table is always used)? I'm on Laravel version 8.29.0.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found it!

In my example, I am creating a custom ForgotPasswordController.

The broker () function does not work as originally declared.

You have to do this:

```
public function sendResetLink(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

        $status = Password::broker('digitalpet_users')->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT ? response()->json(200) : response()->json($status, 500);
    }
```